# How to make place multiple categories in one graph in excel

Tags: excel, graph

I am working on a project which has a data which looks something like this(Data attached in the image)

[DATA FOR THE GRAPH](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PE1KD.png)
The data has % limit for different sectors for each month from jan to july for round about 40 sectors month on month(here just demonstrated 5) The percent utilization can be beyond 100% which which means the sector is overutilised. All I want to show is that how is the movements becoming the sector i.e if the month on month movement is from 82%,83%,85%,89%(just for example) this is not so much alarming but is the movement is from 89%,90%,97%,101% this is alarming one because the sector is slowly and gradually moving towards the 100% limit and even crossing sometimes. All I want to show in an excel graph for all the 40 sectors.how is the month on month movement going on and where it is about to cross the limit of 100%. 
I tried this using multiple ways (bar, column) but all the graphs looks a lot cluttered. how can I show the month on month movement for each sector in one graph for all the 40 sectors.

Line, Bar , Column charts look a lot cluttered when I plot all the sectors together a plot the utilization. Also, For me what is more important is to highlight how can I show which sectors have a vast movement month on month but which sectors do not have.

Can anyone please help me on this.

Thanks in advace